Is there a SwiftUI way to make a window not closable in a macOS app?
For a macOS SwiftUI app, is there a way to make it so a window cannot be closed?
I want to:

Deactivate the close button—red circle—at the top left of the window.
Disable the File -> Close menu command (but just for the one window).

What I’m looking for is a SwiftUI-native way to do this, without having to delve into the NSWindow underpinnings. (Although, my searching so far suggests that that may be the only way—such as discussed in this old question.)
